# capistrano deployment fails db:migrate after release upgrade to focal fossa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ubuntu-20.04

I just upgrade my server to ubuntu 20 LTS, Focal Fossa. Afterwards some stuff did not work as it should. One thing I would like to ask you for help is, that my Rails app is no longer deployable with capistrano. Right before the upgrade it worked.

I just run from remote:
cap staging deploy

Eveything works fine, authentication at github and so on, but at the db:migrate part it fails with the following info:

```
 deploy:migrating
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
LoadError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - 
/home/prod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so

...

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as prod@serverip: Exception while executing as prod@serverip: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/prod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
```

The file is there and the user prod has all rights to access it. There is only one version of ruby on the server installed by rvm. The latest version of openssl is installed on the server. Postgres is running and contains lists all databases as it should.

here the version list from the gemfile.lock:

```
  capistrano (3.14.1)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (2.0.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-npm (1.0.3)
      capistrano (>= 3.0.0)
    capistrano-nvm (0.0.7)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
```

What can I do, i hope you can help me!

Thanks and best regards,
Stephan

Comment: Which database are you using? What's in your `config/database.yml` file? You will need to remove the database gem, and then `bundle install` it again afterwards

Comment: I would try to reinstall the openssl package in your OS and reinstall the ruby version with RVM.

Comment: I updated rvm and reinstalled openssl. Furthermore I had a bug in the staging.rb, where I set a non-existing env. Thanks for your hints and help!